# Visual Studio Professional 2019 NuGet Browse Timeout Error

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, timeout, visual-studio-2019

Everyone.  Thanks for reading.

In Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 version 16.10.4, after starting VS 19, loading a solution with 17 packages, I go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution... and the "Nuget - Solution" tab appears in VS 19.  "Browse" is select by default, in that tab, and it begins to connect to nuget.org as the package source.  Eventually I get this error:

```
[nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
  The HTTP request to 'GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json' has timed out after 100000ms.
```

Is anyone else getting this error?  If so, how did you fix it?  I've tried shutting down VS 19, and removing NuGet.Config from:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet
```

After restarting VS 19, and using NuGet package manager, it regenerates the NuGet.Config file.  Also, while I was getting this issue, Microsoft released VS 19 version 16.10.4.  Originally this was happening in 16.10.3.  The issue continued consistently from 16.10.3 and after the update to 16.10.4.

Also, I can open a browser tab and hit https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json directly.  It must be something specific to VS 19, and not my internet connection.

Any ideas on a fix?  Thanks again, All.

Comment: Do you run any local proxy debugging tools on your machine?

Comment: No. I'm connecting over a VPN, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Did you have a try to connect nuget server in visual studio without VPN?

Comment: Thanks @DylanZhu-MSFT  Connecting without using the VPN worked.  It's odd, b/c I've never had a problem using the same VPN and connecting to nuget in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Dylan Zhu-MSFT  Yes, turning off the VPN, going through the process mentioned in the question, and it does connect to nuget successfully.  I see updates for installed packages, and it's returning results for searches.  No errors. Thanks.